# SVG textLength doesn't work, any other solution?

Tags: text, svg, fonts, size, inkscape

I'm having some troubles with texts in SVG, anyone could help me please?

I'd like to fit a text inside a polygone I already drew. The center of the text is perfect, but I can't control the size of the text.

Whatever I put for textLength, the text remains the same with inkscape.

```
<text id="monId" x="100" y="70" textLength="100" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" fill="red" stroke="darkred" stroke-width=".2" alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">Mon texte</text>
```

How to control the length (and the height) of the text? text-font works to change the size, but it doesn't show me the precise size. What does text-font="55" means precisely in a relation with the length of the text? I tried text-font="55px" but it doesn't change anything : it is way bigger than 55 pixels.

Thank you very much

Comment: you might try converting it into a definition and inserting it as a <use> element. Haven't tried it - just a suggestion.

Comment: The attribute you are looking for is `font-size` not `text-font`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for letter spacing and line spacing in inkscape:

**Letter spacing**

```
Alt +>  expand line/paragraph by 1 
Shift + Alt +>  expand line/paragraph by 10 pixels
Alt +<  contract line/paragraph by 1 pixel
Shift + Alt +<  contract line/paragraph by 10 pixels
These commands (only when editing text) adjust letter spacing in the current line (regular text) or paragraph (flowed text).
The actual adjustment for pixel movements depends on zoom level. Zoom in for finer adjustment.
```

**Line spacing**

```
Ctrl + Alt +>   make the text object taller by 1 pixel
Shift + Ctrl + Alt +>   make the text object taller by 10 pixels
Ctrl + Alt +<   make the text object shorter by 1 pixel
Shift + Ctrl + Alt +<   make the text object shorter by 10 pixels
These commands (only when editing text) adjust line spacing in the entire text object (regular or flowed).
The actual adjustment for pixel movements depends on zoom level. Zoom in for finer adjustment.
```

Source: [Inkscape shortcuts](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/keys091.html)